# Sliding menu using jfeinstein10 Dex Loader

Tags: android

Here are my errors:

```
[2013-04-24 16:56:55 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2013-04-24 16:56:55 - ExampleListActivity] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

I'm trying to launch the examplelistactivity. In android properties i have the library's defined but not in the build path... no duplicate lib names... I still cannot find a solution.

I have 3 android-support-v4.jar all in different projects so i renamed them all... what other option should i take?

EDIT: I removed the files from both libs and it works!

Comment: You have 2 android v4 support libs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I removed the files from both libs and it works!